# Ionic 2 Missing source to debug on ios device

Tags: ionic2, source-maps, safari-web-inspector

I am an experienced Ionic 1.xx developer but am struggling with my first attempt at debugging an Ionic 2 ios app on the device.  Android is no problem, can chrome://inspect and build with --debug option and get full access to .ts source files for setting break points from chrome.  However, when building for ios ( ionic build ios --debug ) it webpacks everything and no .ts files are available from Safari Web Inspector when running on the device.

My config files (tsconfig, package.json ) are obviously working right because the build works fine ( sourcemaps enabled, etc ) for android.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So unlike when debugging with 1.xx,  you can not visually traverse a source code tree and select the file you would like to debug.  **Instead you have to search for it.**

So the sourcemaps are there.  So if you search for .ts you will get be able to select it and then set breaks and debug like normal!

Yeah! Now on to more important things...